# executing scripts on Google App Engine localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, bash

is there an easy way to execute scripts on Google App Engine localhost?
For instance i have few scripts to generate pilot data, it's quite painful to copy-and-paste them to the interactive console all the time.

Currently, i'm using a simple bash script to do this, but i'm not sure this is the best solution.

`` curl --data-urlencode "code=`cat src/gen_pilot_data.py`" http://localhost:8079/_ah/admin/interactive/execute ``

thanks,
 V

Answer (score 3):

Check out remote_api_shell.py, included in the SDK. This lets you run code on your local machine against APIs on your App Engine app, be they in production or on the dev_appserver.

The other option you have is to make your scripts into handlers, and simply GET or POST to the relevant URLs.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer Nick. can you elaborate on how to use the remote_api_shell.py locally? things have changed quite a bit and it's asking me for credentials. i have set those up for develop and production instances before but never for a local environment. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to do in order to execute script on AppEngine, but if you want to use AppEngine APIs you have to boot AppEngine before. I don't know the builtin one-line way, but you can take look how various projects do this:

https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/src/4f5d7a223084/boot.py

http://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/source/browse/trunk/nosegae.py?r=54

You can also try to import your script in console:

```
import gen_pilot_data
```

Comment: you can write files into GAE?